# JSPM System.import 404s

Tags: jspm

I am trying to learn JSPM as it seems like it is the future for installing client-side JavaScript.  I am NOT attempting to use ES6 or TypeScript but am actually using CoffeeScript which I compile into 'standard' JavaScript for the browser.  I am running node.js in express with my public files contained in ./public and accessible from the path /.

Having installed jspm my package.json configuration is:

```
"jspm": {
  "directories": {
    "baseURL": "public",
    "packages": "public/lib"
  }
}
```

It is configured like so:

```
System.config({
  baseUrl: '/',
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: false,
  paths: {}
});
```

With this setup I run: `jspm install lodash` which installs the package in `public/lib/npm/lodash@4.5.1`.  In my application JavaScript I would expect to be able to run:

```
System.import('lodash');
```

and would expect that to return a Promise.  However, I get a 404 on /lodash.js.  So, in an effort to fix this I decided to use the explicit path to lodash: `lib/npm/lodash@4.5.1/lodash`.  That seems to resolve the lodash 404 but then I get a 404 for `/buffer.js` and `/process.js` which I assume are dependencies of lodash.

Surely there has to be a better way than this?  What am I missing here?!  Part of the difficulty I am having is that most of the examples seem to use ES6 import directives which are irrelevant to me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing some paths on your systemjs config:

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: false,
  paths: {
    "github:*": "lib/github/*",
    "npm:*": "lib/npm/*"
  },

  map: {
    "lodash": "npm:lodash@4.6.1",
    ...
    "npm:lodash@4.6.1": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    ...
  }
});
```

Also, you should have the lodash dependency declared on your package.json:

```
{
  "jspm": {
    "directories": {
      "baseURL": "public",
      "packages": "public/lib"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "lodash": "npm:lodash@^4.6.1"
    }
  }
}
```